# Android ICS Spinner with actionbarsherlock

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, android-spinner

Hi Guys
I want to use ICS spinner in my android application so i can move between views (min API 10), I'm using ABS.
So how can i add and use spinner( but please A detailed explanation  ) in my case, and how to add additional  button in the ABS?
Thax for your time :)

Comment: I'm really need a help here

Comment: Please feel free to edit your question to explain what you consider "ICS spinner" and "additional button" to be.

Comment: @CommonsWare ICS Spinner : like the gamil application to choose between your account, additional button like the share button in ICS action bar but to do another job like creating something add somthing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ICS Spinner : like the gamil application to choose between your account

Use `setNavigationMode()` and `NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST` with `ActionBar`, as is illustrated in [this sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/ListNav) and as is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown).

> additional button like the share button in ICS action bar but to do another job like creating something add somthing

You do this the same way that you add items to the overflow menu (or the old options menu), except that you include `android:showAsAction` in your menu XML (e.g., `android:showAsAction="always"`), as is illustrated in [this sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/ActionBarDemo) and as is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems).

Comment: thx a lot man, I really appreciate your fast respond :)
I'll try it and give you the feedback.

Comment: @CommonsWare is IF/ELSE around the ArrayAdapter really necessary (from your ListNav demo)?

Comment: @BryanDenny: If you mean as to whether or not to use `getThemedContext()`, yes, if you want the drop-down list to look correct, IIRC.

Comment: @CommansWare It looks correct to me with only using `getThemedContext()`, tested on Galaxy Nexus Android 4.1 and OG Droid CM7.1 (Android 2.3)

Comment: @BryanDenny: I am going by the documentation for `getThemedContext()` (http://goo.gl/32lC1) and what I have read.