# How do I change the color of the spinner when using NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-spinner

I can't seem to figure out how to make the spinner turn white:

[image]

What style do I need to apply to get it to change to white? I'm using ActionBarSherlock.

Relevant code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    ....
    // Just a class to hold description/value pairs
    DescriptionValuePair[] pastdays = new DescriptionValuePair[] {   
            new DescriptionValuePair("Past 30 days", "30"), 
            new DescriptionValuePair("Past 60 days", "60"), 
            new DescriptionValuePair("Past 90 days", "90"), 
            };
    ArrayAdapter adapter_pastdays = null;

    ActionBar bar=getSupportActionBar();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        adapter_pastdays = new ArrayAdapter(bar.getThemedContext(), R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, pastdays );
    }
    else {
        adapter_pastdays = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, pastdays );
    }

    adapter_pastdays.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    bar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter_pastdays, this);
 }
```

Comment: Note: Changing the theme to `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar` from `Theme.Sherlock.Light` works, but I don't want to change the theme, only the text color and corner arrow button to white.

Comment: Why are you conditionally creating the `ArrayAdapter`? The former version should work on all API levels.

Comment: @JakeWharton Was using CommonGuy's example here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/ActionBar/ListNav/src/com/commonsware/android/listnav/ListNavFragmentDemoActivity.java I didn't *think* it was relevant either, thanks for confirming that suspicion

Comment: Additionally, I think I'm going to just change the theme to `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar` but it may still be worthwhile if someone knows how to change just the drop down styles

Comment: Relevant: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1285

Comment: @JakeWharton See CommonGuy's response, but it looks fine to me with only `getThemedContext()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786577/android-ics-spinner-with-actionbarsherlock/13789069#comment19191679_13789069